# Meteor React not updating reactively when field on user profile is changed?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Im using React with Meteor. Ive added a field to user profiles which can change however I don't see these changes until I refresh the page. I've disabled autopublish.

In my server file I have an account creation hook:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  user.groups = [1];
  return user;
});
```

Im publishing the field:

```
Meteor.publish('currentUser', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId }, { fields: { groups: 1 } });
});
```

In my GroupsPage React component Im subscribing to this publication:

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('currentUser');
  return {
    ready: true,
  };
})(GroupsPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should query this user inside your tracker like this:
```

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  let sub = Meteor.subscribe('currentUser');
  // Reactive source
  let user = Meteor.users.findOne();
  return {
    ready: sub.ready(),
    user: user
  };
})(GroupsPage);
```

```

Comment: I needed to change  sub.isReady to  sub.ready but then it works.